# Celery with redis got a huge key named celery

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I am using Celery with redis. I got a problem is in the redis a key named redis length is 8450468. It's too long and too huge.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> llen celery
(integer) 8450468
```

My question is:

- how to clean this list
- why this happen

Here is my celery settings

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://queuem/'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'queue:liveapp:default'
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'liveapp.logic.broadcast.task_pubnub_publish_to_channel_broadcast_likes_of_user': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:like'},
    'liveapp.logic.broadcast.task_pubnub_like_broadcast': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:like'},
    'liveapp.logic.broadcast.task_bots_join_broadcast': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:bot'},
    'liveapp.logic.broadcast.task_bot_join_broadcast': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:bot'},
    'liveapp.logic.broadcast.task_bot_leave_broadcast': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:bot'},
    'liveapp.logic.message.task_push_message_to_users': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:message'},
    'liveapp.logic.message.task_pubnub_send_message': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:message'},
    'liveapp.logic.message.task_yunba_send_broadcast_message': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:message'},
    'liveapp.logic.conversation.task_yunba_send_message': {'queue': 'queue:liveapp:message'},
}

CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT = False

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```